# utf8_encode of uppercase letter error

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to encode a string that contains accented uppercase letter like:

```
$string = "This is a test - À ";
```

i'm trying to encode using `utf8_encode` in this way:

```
$string  = "This is a test - À ";
$encoded = utf8_encode($string);
```

And returned string is:

```
"This is a test - ã ";
```

What function can i use instead `utf8_encode` ?

**EDIT**

This string is stored into a table in mysql db.

This is how i connect to database:

```
$host = "xxxxxx:3306";
$uid =  "username";
$pwd =  "password";
$dv_database_name = "db_name";

$db_dv = mysql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd);

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8",$db_dv);
$sql = "...";
$res = mysql_query($sql, $db_dv);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$string = $row['myField']; // THIS IS THE STRING WITH ACCENTED VALUE
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `utf8_encode`?

Comment: to encode string to show it correctly in html

Comment: @JackTurky: is your php file written in ISO-8859-1?

Comment: no. This string is stored in UTF-8 into a mysql DB

Comment: So there is no need to use utf8_encode `utf8_encode — Encodes an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8`. All you need to do is make utf-8 connection to db `SET NAMES utf8` and set proper HTML header `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the problem is with your original string: are you sure the editor you edit it with is in utf8 mode?
[utf8_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) is only capable to transcode from ISO-8859-1 to UFT8

I see your code. I would suggest to follow directions in the comments to your question. No need to use utf8_encode, if everything is already UTF8.

Be sure that html page presenting the results to the user has explictit UTF8 encoding (as suggested by Peter).

Comment: Sorry but the string is stored into mysql in utf8. Using GUI db editor i show string correctly

Comment: So please show the code you use to connect to db and to extract the data (hiding passwords, of course... :-)